# How get multiple URL value in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

How to get multiple argument values in Laravel 5.2?

Example:

```
http://localhost:8000/print?id=1&id=3
```

How get the values of `id`s in an array let's say `[1,2]`?

Comment: What exactly you want to do ?

Comment: If you want to get values of id use array,`http://localhost:8000/print?id[]=1&id[]=3` and check

Answer (score 3):

You can send the data using `[]` in the url as:

```
http://localhost:8000/print?id[]=1&id[]=3
```

Then you can get it in controller as:

```
$request->get('id') // returns [1,3]
```